# I want to get the specific prediction of my Deep-Learning- CNN-model to a probability

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I trained a model to categorize pictures in 7 different types.  my Model can only do a specific
prediction (numpy.ndarray in my case), but I am interested to have a prediction which is more
like a probability (For example 90% class1 and 80% class2 ...etc). Where is the part of my code
which I should change now? how l get correct Probability value using the train model for each
class

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Lambda, Dense,Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.applications.inception_v3 import preprocess_input  
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator,load_img
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
import numpy as np
from glob import glob
from google.colab import drive

from google.colab import drive 
drive.mount('/content/drive')

IMAGE_SIZE = [244,244]

train_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Programs/Datasets/Train'
test_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Programs/Datasets/Test'
```

```
folders = glob('/content/drive/MyDrive/Programs/Datasets/Train/*')
```

7 categories

['/content/drive/MyDrive/Programs/Datasets/Train/Circle',
'/content/drive/MyDrive/Programs/Datasets/Train/Grapes',
'/content/drive/MyDrive/Programs/Datasets/Train/Sun',
'/content/drive/MyDrive/Programs/Datasets/Train/Tree',
'/content/drive/MyDrive/Programs/Datasets/Train/Square',
'/content/drive/MyDrive/Programs/Datasets/Train/Triangle',
'/content/drive/MyDrive/Programs/Datasets/Train/Leaf',
'/content/drive/MyDrive/Programs/Datasets/Train/Pencil']

````
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
 
     tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(30, (4, 4), activation='relu', input_shape=(224, 224, 3)),
 

     tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
 

     tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(60, (2, 2), activation='relu'),
 

     tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),


     tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
 

     tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
 

     tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),


     tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, activation='relu'),
 

     tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(folders), activation='softmax')])

 model.summary()




 train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                shear_range = 0.2,
                                zoom_range = 0.2,
                                horizontal_flip = True)


 test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)



 training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_path,
                                              target_size = (224,224),
                                              batch_size = 16,
                                              class_mode = 'categorical')



 test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(test_path,
                                         target_size = (224, 224),
                                         batch_size = 16,
                                         class_mode = 'categorical')

 model.compile(
         loss='categorical_crossentropy',
         optimizer='adam',
         metrics=['accuracy']
 )


 #Traning
 r = model.fit_generator(
         training_set,
         validation_data=test_set,
         epochs=5,
         steps_per_epoch=len(training_set),
         validation_steps=len(test_set)
 )


 

 from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

 model.save('my_model.h5')

 ```

  Model prediction Part

 ```
 y_pred = model.predict(test_set)

 import numpy as np
 y_pred = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)


 from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
 from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image

 model=load_model('my_model.h5')

 img=image.load_img('/content/drive/MyDrive/Programs/Datasets/circle604.jpg',target_size= 
 (224,224))

 x=image.img_to_array(img)
 x=x/255

 import numpy as np
 x=np.expand_dims(x,axis=0)
 img_data=preprocess_input(x)
 img_data.shape

 model.predict(img_data)
 ```
 out put of model.predict(img_data)

 array([[6.1735226e-09, 5.3491673e-11, 1.6549424e-09, 9.9484622e-01,
     5.1531033e-03, 7.3390618e-07, 2.1824545e-16, 4.2561878e-11]],
   dtype=float32)
 ```
 # Predict with test data
 predictions = model.predict(img_data)

 # getting the highet probable digit
 predicted_value = np.argmax(model.predict(img_data))

 print("The set of predicted values")
 print(model.predict(img_data))
 print("\nPredicted Class : ", predicted_value)
 print("Probability of the Class being ", predicted_value, " is : ", 
 max(model.predict(img_data)), "\n")

 print(type(model.predict(img_data)))
 ```



 #I want get class name and Probability vale for prediction  
 #But output results is 

 The set of predicted values
 [[6.1735226e-09 5.3491673e-11 1.6549424e-09 9.9484622e-01 5.1531033e-03
   7.3390618e-07 2.1824545e-16 4.2561878e-11]]

 Predicted Class :  3
 Probability of the Class being  3  is :  [6.1735226e-09 5.3491673e-11 1.6549424e-09 
 9.9484622e-01 5.1531033e-03
 7.3390618e-07 2.1824545e-16 4.2561878e-11] 

 <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
````

Comment: Please **fix** your code formatting; do not bury text into the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all there are 8 categories. Secondly the output of the prediction has shape (1,8) which is technically a list of a single list(a row of column data) so by passing in `model.predict(img_data)` you are going to get back the row.
What you need to do is `max(model.predict(img_data)[0])` to get the highest value.

To get the class name, that has to do with the method of encoding used on your labels.

Also, if you want, as you stated, your probabilities of each class to be in this form, 90% class1 and 80% class2 ...etc, you should use `sigmoid` instead of `softmax` as your activation function in the output layer. `softmax` enforces that for each sample, the sum of all classes probabilities is 1 (it is used when classes are exclusive - example: 60 % probability rainy, 40 % probability not rainy), which is not what you want.

Comment: to get your predictions as percentages you have to multiply them by 100 and format them.  So to get the max as a percentage you can do  this `f"{round(max(model.predict(img_data)[0])*100,2)}%"`

Answer (score 0):

`predictions` hold the "probability" for each class. The `argmax` bit is selecting the class with maximum "probability"